# Who will the moderators be?

Tags: support, moderation

As of 5 minutes ago, I was a moderator simply due to my 2.5k rep and commitment to Chiphacker carrying over.  Now, however, I'm unable to close my own duplicate question.  I still have access to the moderation tools, but I don't have the diamond by my name, or the ability to singlehandedly close a question. Something is going on here.

Is this intentional?  Should we start asking who the moderators are going to be, or maybe wait a few days to see who emerges as leaders in the beta?

Comment: Shouldn't anyone over 2000 rep automatically be a moderator?

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be a good thing for those who were active moderators on Chiphacker to continue their role here, at least for the duration of the beta.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should follow up on with Robert Cartaino -- email him at rcartaino@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Do you mean that those that are interested should email him?

Comment: @kortuk we can't make any guarantees but it doesn't *hurt* to do so

Comment: I was ensuring you were not just answering the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Kortuk: I received your message and have contacted you via email.